# Displaying JSON data on front-end using fetch

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, gatsby

So really new to React here, and I want to make a simple search box, where the user submits a "question" and the JSON returns the values of "results".

The request goes through and I get a response, only thing I can't find is taking the results from it and displaying them on the front end.

```
class Search extends Component {
    state = {
      searchValue: "",
      searchSection: "",
      results: [],
      // section: []
    };

    handleOnChange = event => {
      this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
    };

    handleSearch = () => {
      this.makeApiCall(this.state.searchValue);
    };

    makeApiCall() {
      fetch("http://example.com/json", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            question: (this.state.searchValue),
            section: (this.state.searchSection),
        })
    })

        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(
            "POST Response",
            "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
          )
            return responseData
        })
      .then(results => this.setState({results: results.value}))
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div id="main" className="py-16">
          <label className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
              Ask a question
          </label>
          <input
            name="text"
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
            value={this.state.searchValue}
            className="shadow-sm appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleSearch} className="cursor-pointer mt-5 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded-full shadow">Search</button>

          // DISPLAYING THEM ON THE FRONT HERE
          {this.state.results ? (
            <div id="question-container">
              {this.state.results.map((result) => (
                <div className="result">
                  <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                  <p>{result.sentences}</p>
                </div>
              ))}

            </div>
          ) : (
            <p>Can't find results for your question</p>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Search;
```

My JSON is like:

```
{
  "request": {
    "date_from": "", 
    "date_to": "", 
    "question": "User question here", 
    "section": null
  }, 
  "results": {
    "docs": [
      {
      "title": " "
      "section": " "
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

And I need to display multiple questions from the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the help of Sarthak Aggarwal and Bamuleseyo Gideon (thanks Gideon) I found the solution to this.

The actual problem was that I was not targeting the correct property Sarthak said. But also `results.docs`was wrong.

So, instead of

`.then(results => this.setState({results: results.value}))`

I changed it to

```
  .then(jsonData => {
    this.setState({ docs: jsonData.results.docs });
  });
``

and it works like a charm :)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `makeApiCall`, change `results.value` to `results.docs` as your JSON has `docs` property which has all the data you want to display.

```
makeApiCall() {
      fetch("http://example.com/json", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            question: (this.state.searchValue),
            section: (this.state.searchSection),
        })
    })

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(
            "POST Response",
            "Response Body -> " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
          )
            return responseData
        })
      .then(results => {
          this.setState({
           results: results.docs
          },()=>console.log(this.state)) 
      })
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Sarthak! I still get the "Can't find results for your question" response though, something must be wrong when getting the response in `{this.state.results ? (
            <div id="question-container">
              {this.state.results.map((result) => (
                <div className="result">
                  <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                  <p>{result.sentences}</p>
                </div>
              ))}
              
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p>Can't find results for your question</p>
          )}`

Comment: Check your state once after `setState`. Updated the code for the same also.

Comment: `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`:/

Comment: There was a missing ')' @KostasVrouvas

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working....  in console I get `results: undefined
​
searchSection: ""
​
searchValue: ""`

And the answer-container div is not showing results. Instead I get the no results div.

I originally followed this: https://github.com/lytes20/meal-search-app and reorganized it to get a POST request. But it seems there is a problem in the "render" part...

Comment: @KostasVrouvas are you getting `results.docs` in your API response ?

Comment: This is what I get. The first one is the console.log I already had and the second is a result from your code: https://imgur.com/a/773ALZU